# Checking whether a word (value) is in a comma-separated list

Tags: shell-script, pattern-matching

In below code, `2` should not match with `21`,
but it gives a result "matched".

How can I check whether the `SOURCE` value is in the `LIST`?

```
LIST="1,21,3,4"
SOURCE="2"
if echo "$LIST" | grep -q "$SOURCE"; then
  echo "matched";
else
  echo "no match";
fi
```

Comment: How is `LIST` being generated?  You should really do something (almost anything) else than store this all in a single CSV variable.

Comment: Your "list", `1,21,3,4`, is a string of characters.  One of these characters is `2`, which is why your regular expression matches it.  It is unclear what you want to do and, as Jesse_b said, where the data comes from.  If you can give a bit more context, someone would be able to give you a proper answer.

Answer (score 7):

The standard trick is

```
if echo ",$LIST," | grep -q ",$SOURCE,"
then
  echo "matched"
else
  echo "no match"
fi
```

(or you can say `grep -q ",$SOURCE," <<< ",$LIST,"`). 
Searching for `2` will match `21`,
but searching for `,2,` will not match `,21,`. 
We need to put commas at the beginning and end of `$LIST`
in case the `$SOURCE` number we are looking for
is the first or the last number; for example,

```
grep -q ",1," <<< "1,21,3,4"
```

will fail.

Answer (score 2):

Your use of "word" is a suggestion (to me) that you could use grep's word boundary constructions:

```
LIST="1,21,3,4"
SOURCE="2"
if echo "$LIST" | grep -q "\\<$SOURCE\\>"; then
  echo "matched";
else
  echo "no match";
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

```
list="1,21,3,4"
source=2

awk -F, -v search="$source" '{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if ($i==search) {print $i} } }' <<<"$list"
```

---

You're searching for `2` within the entire string and `21` does in fact contain `2`.

If your entire string is always comma separated you could also do:

```
grep -E ',2,|,2$|^2,'
```

This would find a `2` in the beginning, middle, or end of the list.

Comment: Without the explicit loop: `awk -v RS=',' '$1 == 2 { ok=1; exit } END { printf("%smatch\n", (ok ? "" : "no ")) }'`